# Best way to target a list of buttons to get their value?

Tags: javascript, dom

What is the best way to target a list of say 10 buttons all with different values?

I believe it would be `getElementbyId` but i am unsure how i would use this in a function / onlick

Comment: Give them all the same class, then use `document.getElementByClassName()` and loop over the result.

Comment: this depending on their context

Comment: Do you want to get the value of these buttons or setup a click handler on each of them?

Comment: @customcommander Its basically the start of a game where theres 10 boxes. The first button they click, this will become their box for the rest of the game. So the value of that box is needed, (the values start at 1 and go up to 10) the rest of the game is them selecting buttons which will randomly select a value from an array and remove it .

Comment: @customcommander i now have it set up where it correctly selects a random button and shows the value however im not sure how to assign a value from the array at random to it for the rest of the game without showing that to the user. Also getting the functions together while setting up conditions is becoming challenging

Answer (score 0):

Check out the MDN documentation for [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) and [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) which include examples.

For a brief overview,

```
document.querySelectorAll('button')
    .forEach((button, i) =>
        button.addEventListener('click', () => console.log(`button ${i} clicked!`)));
```